# SQL MAX(dob) not returning in inner join with conditions

Tags: sql, oracle, join, max

In trying to find the basic details of a doctor (name, address phone etc)  where they are the youngest working in the clinic, but also have not resigned.

I've gone through forums and the best I've found is to use an inner join, but now it's not returning any information at all.

```
select doctorid, surname, given, address, suburb, postcode, phone
from doctor 
inner join (
        select max(dob)
        from doctor
        where resigned is null);
```

this code isn't working, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Inner join syntax seems wrong, you didn't mention here on which field you are making join, @andomar corrected it properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `inner join` requires an `on` clause:

```
from doctor 
inner join (
    select max(dob) as max_dob
    from doctor
    where resigned is null) filter
on filter.max_dob = doctor.dob
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
   select d1.doctorid, d1.surname, d1.given, d1.address, 
   d1.suburb, d1.postcode, d1.phone
   from doctor d1 join doctor d2
   on d1.doctorid<> d2.doctorid and d1.dob>=d2.dob
   group by d1.doctorid
   having count(*)= (select count(*)-1 from doctor);
```